# How to make background images clickable (javascript or css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image, clickable

Please take a look this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MSBBg/)

How to make the background image clickable? When click "Take the survey" will go to a new page.

```
<div style="height:300px;width:300px;border-style:solid;border-width:5px;background-image:url('http://cdn.survey.io/embed/1.0/right_top_blue.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right top;">

By default, the background-image property repeats an image both horizontally and vertically.

</div>
```

Javascript or CSS are all preferred.

Edit: I don't want to use image float to right corner.

Comment: why do you use that image as a background? if would be more logical wrap a regular <img> in a <a> element. And float is not necessary if you don't want use it

Comment: please give a example on not using float.

Comment: You cant register a handle to a background image. You'll have to go with something like this: [fiddle-fork](http://jsfiddle.net/EdRSC/)

Comment: @sophia take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't.

What if a user has styles turned off, or is using a screen reader? They should be able to take the survey as well.

```
div{position:relative;}
a {display:block; width:120px; height:120px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; right:0;
    text-indent:-9999px;

    background-image:url('http://cdn.survey.io/embed/1.0/right_top_blue.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right top;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MSBBg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Check here for more info: http://bluedogwebservices.com/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/

Also, you could make the div relative, then just put image wrapped with anchor and position it absolutely in top right corner.

Edit

Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="/"><img src="yoursrc" alt="description"/></a>
<p>Some other text regularly positioned.</p>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper
{
position:relative;
width:500px;
height:500px;
}

.wrapper a
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Please can you give a live fiddle example on "you could make the div relative, then just put image wrapped with anchor and position it absolutely in top right corner"

Comment: that is clever, but it's kind of a hack. Granted, it works :).

Answer (score 1):

that's a simple example using position relative + absolute

http://jsfiddle.net/RZWCS/

you could also think to absolute positioning the link and use that image as link background (the text of the link could be the same appearing on the image and moved outside with negative text-indent or similar techniques)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but I don't think that CSS backgrounds can have events bound to them. I would personally cover it with a transparent div, or use a real image to tap into the events of the DOM element.

I would be interested if someone had a way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Just turn the div into an `<a>` element?

```
<a href="mysite.com" 
    style="display: block; 
    height:300px; 
    width:300px;
    border: 5px solid;
    background: url('http://cdn.survey.io/embed/1.0/right_top_blue.png') right top no-repeat;">
<a/>
```