# How do i make only the image part of an element clickable?

Tags: html, css

When i use

```
background: url("button.png") top/contain no-repeat;
```

It will fit the image correctly.
But when i make the div clickable, it will receive clicks from all over the div and not only the part with the image on it, can it be fixed somehow?

Comment: `<a href="..."><img src="button.jpg"></a>`

Comment: @MörreNoseshine it is a background image defined in css

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the image as background and don't just put an `img` tag inside your div?

Comment: OMG  @MörreNoseshine you are right! so simple! and all i have to do now is to add width="100%" so it will fit itself to the screen while rotating it! Thanks! :)

Comment: @MörreNoseshine i thought that you are misunderstand the question and just wanna warn you. of course the simpliest solution is the perfect one.

Comment: @semirturgay Warn me from what? It was obvious that OP doesn't give nearly enough information to help solve his *actual problem*. My answer was 90% meant to point that out by deliberately solving exactly and *only* the problem he asked about. The question really is too broad since there are many options and possibilities depending on what the guy actually wants to do, context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make background images clickable (javascript or css)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811311/how-to-make-background-images-clickable-javascript-or-css)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set your `div` to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Besides from that, you don't want to have a padding in the `div`. Instead only set height and width to the exact dimensions for the button. If you want to align the button you can use `margin`.

```
div.myButton {
    background: url("button.png") top/contain no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    height:30px; /* For example 30px */
    width:80px; /* By 80px*/
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```